# Taylor series, identify radius of convergence

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have the following function :
[image]

I need to find it's radius of convergence with z0 = 0. The function is analytic everywhere except where

```
1 + sin(iz) = 0
```

(to my understanding). So according to the following theorem (free translation)

If f(z) is analytic inside a circle C centered at z0, then for every z inside C, the Taylor serie exist.

I then need to find the smallest radius which is the smallest point where

```
1 + sin(iz) = 0
```

If my theory is correct, how can I find those point? sin(iz) is not something we can represent on a graph.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful identity is:
Sin(iz)= i Sinh(z).

Comment: it gives me an idea.... gonna try something!!!

Answer (score 0):

I used arcsin(-1) = iz.

Can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the complex representation, $$sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ and set $1+sin(iz)=0$ there should be infinitely many solutions. Find the one which is closest to 0 and find the distance

$$1+\frac{e^{-z}-e^{z}}{2i}=0 \Rightarrow z=\frac{i(4\pi n+\pi)}{2},n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
The closest answer to $0$ is $n=0$ which the distance to $0$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
So the radius of convergence at $z_0=0$ of $\frac{z^2}{1+sin(iz)}$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$